# Continuous Markov chain - expected time

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I have been studying problems from some of my lecture notes and was given this question

> A continuous time Markov Chain $X_t$ with state space $\{1,2,3\}$ has infinitesimal generator 
>   $$A= \begin{bmatrix}-6 & 2 & 4\\2 &-5 &3 \\2 & 3& -5\end{bmatrix}$$
>   If the chain starts in state 2, what is expected total time spent in state 2 before the chain first enters state 3

In the solution the answer is given as $$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{2}{15}+\frac{1}{5}(\frac{2}{15})^{2}+.......= \frac{\frac{1}{5}}{1-\frac{2}{15}}$$

I know from my lectures notes that
The expected time at state 2 is: $(\frac{1}{5})$

The chain jumps to state 1 with probability $(\frac{2}{5})$ and state 3 with probability  $(\frac{3}{5})$

and I know chain jumps from 1 to 2 with probability $(\frac{1}{3})$

so the probability that the chain return to state 2 in two steps, starting at 2 is thus $(\frac{2}{5})(\frac{1}{3})=(\frac{2}{15})$

So after finding these probabilities I can understand the right hand side of the equation given in the solution but im confused about how it becomes  $$\frac{\frac{1}{5}}{1-\frac{2}{15}}$$

I have been looking through my notes and haven't been able to find anything. Any help would be great

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty ax^n=\frac a{1-x}\qquad (a=1/5,\ x=2/15)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  In this particular case you could say:

$$S = \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{2}{15}+\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)^{2}+\cdots$$

multiplying by $\frac2{15}$ gives 
$$\frac2{15}S = \frac{1}{5}\frac{2}{15}+\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{5}\left(\frac{2}{15}\right)^{3}+\cdots$$

and subtracting gives 
$$\left(1-\frac2{15}\right)S = \frac{1}{5}$$

so 
$$S = \frac{\frac{1}{5}}{1-\frac2{15}}$$